# Place column value on qtm map

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap, ggmap

I have a map, and would like to place the value of the district

Working code

```
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tmap)

doe <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "doesep")

qtm(shp = doe, fill = "sep12_PERC", fill.palette = "Blues", fill.title = "Installs")
```

Output

[image]

I would like show map with the district number on top, i.e.

[image]

I tried this, but doesn't work (name of Column of districts is "SchoolDist")

```
qtm(shp = doe, fill = "sep12_PERC", fill.palette = "Blues", fill.title = "Installs") + tm_layout(title = "SchoolDist", title.position=c("center", "center"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes! Any idea how to add the column names?